# How to retrieve stores based on the store id

Tags: dojo

I am creating a Memory store as

```
var someData = [
    {id:1, name:"One"},
    {id:2, name:"Two"}
];
store = new Memory({
            data: someData,
            id:”userStore”
});
```

I was wondering if there is a way to query the Memory store to return the store instance by id. Like

```
var storePresent = Memory.getById(“userStore”)
```

something similar to

```
dijit.registry.byId();
```

that returns the instance of dijit specified by id

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is not a store registry as you describe.  You will need to code this yourself in your application's controller code.

A store is a simple Object.

You could:

1. Pass the store manually around your code.
2. Code a registry AMD module (caution, here be dragons).

The only exception to this rule is if you're already using dojox/app as your controller layer. That has some named store abilities.  If not, I would *not* recommend refactoring to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no build-in static repository of memory stores in module `dojo/store/Memory`. If you need something like that, the easiest way is to write custom factory of memory stores that will hold the static references to all stores that are created:

```javascript
define(["dojo/store/Memory"], function(Memory){
  var repository = {}
  return {
    getStore: function(id) {
        return repository[id]
    },
    createStore: function(id, params) {
        var memory = new Memory(params)
        repository[id] = memory
        return memory
    }
  }
});
```

The usage:

```javascript
require(["modules/MemoryRepository"], function(MemoryRepository) {
  MemoryRepository.createStore("userStore", {data: someData})
  ...
  var userStore = MemoryRepository.getStore("userStore")
})
```

If you are to create a lot of stores on demand, you should think of deregistering them (removing the references from the factory) as well. Memory issues are probably the reason something like that is not provided out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answerers already said, there's no specific repository or registry for stores. However, the `dijit/registry` can be used to store the reference as well by using the `dijit/registry::add()` function, for example:

```js
// Add to registry
registry.add(new Memory({
    id: "userStore",
    data: [{
        name: "Smith",
        firstname: "John"
    }, {
        name: "Doe",
        firstname: "John"
    }]
}));
```

Then you can retrieve it by using the `dijit/registry::byId()` function, for example:

```js
// Query the store by using the registry
var person = registry.byId("userStore").query({
    firstname: "John"
}).forEach(function(person) {
    console.log(person.firstname + " " + person.name);
});
```

A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mn94f/